# Serialization of closure failed: The closure was not found within the abstract syntax tree

Tags: laravel, serialization, laravel-5.1, homestead

I am receiving this error in production but not in local testing:

> Serialization of closure failed: The closure was not found within the abstract syntax tree.

I use Homestead/Vagrant on my local machine to ensure the environment is similar to production and I cannot track down why I started receiving this in production when I did not receive it at all in local testing.

The snippet of code is below, any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

```php
foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
    $data = array('eventInfo' => $eventInfo, 'bowlerInfo' => $bowlerInfo, 'bowlerSchoolInfo' => $bowlerSchoolInfo,
        'matchInfo' => $match, 'notificationInfo' => $notification);

    Mail::queue('emails.matchEventAddedNotification', $data, function ($message) use ($notification, $bowlerInfo) {

        $dataHeader['category'] = 'Match Event Notification';
        $dataHeader['unique_args']['message'] = 'Email related to a new match event notification.';
        $dataHeader['unique_args']['bowler_id'] = $bowlerInfo['id'];
        $dataHeader['unique_args']['matchevents_notify_id'] = $notification['id'];
        $header = json_encode($dataHeader);
        $message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', $header);
        $message->subject('New Score Added For' . ' ' . $bowlerInfo['first_name'] . ' ' . $bowlerInfo['last_name']);
        $message->to($notification['email']);
    });

    $matcheventNotify = Matchevent_Notify::find($notification['id']);
    $matcheventNotify->last_sent = Carbon::now();
    $matcheventNotify->save();
}
```

Production Environment

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=XXXXX

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=klaabowling
DB_USERNAME=XXXXXXX
DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXXX

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file

DOMAIN_BASE=klaabowling.com
APP_URL=http://klaabowling.com

AWS_REGION=us-west-2
AWS_AccessKey=XXXXXX
AWS_SecretAccessKey=XXXXXX

GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=XXXXXX
```

Comment: Since you're trying to queue the mail, it might related to your production queues configuration. Can you tell us more about it (maybe share both your .env files - without passwords or api keys obviously)

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have access to my local environment right now but can post it later tonight. My production environment is added to my orginral post. I do know that the local environment does not have an entry for queue driver either. Both local and production are using my default driver of database at this time.

Comment: From what I see your config is missing the `QUEUE_DRIVER` parameter, the default is set to sync as you can see the .env.example file : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example

Comment: My Queue config file sets the default to database if my environment variable is not set: `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),`

Comment: Have you create the migration with the command `php artisan queue:table` and runned it as instructed in the documentation ? https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#introduction

Comment: Yes, the problem does not lie with the queue table. I have other functions using the queue table just fine. The issue is only present on the event listener with the code in my original post..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to track down the issue. The issue was the queue worker I am using in production. I am using a Daemon queue worker but I had failed to restart the queue worker so it was not recognizing my new code. Relevant information from the Laravel documentation:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

[Deploying With Daemon Queue Listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#deploying-with-daemon-queue-listeners)

Comment: I don't know what the reason is, but this certainly did the magic for me. Much obliged!